# Grunt config watch and karma:unit in single task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, karma-runner, grunt-contrib-watch

Currently I have following Gruntfile configuration with two separate tasks and it works perfect:

```
grunt.registerTask('server', [
    'connect',
    'jshint',
    'less:dev',
    'watch'
]);

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'karma:unit'
]);
```

I'd like to make one task that cover both things and log into one terminal window.
Something like:

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', [
    'connect',
    'jshint',
    'less:dev',
    'karma:unit',
    'watch'
]);
```

The problem is that karma and watch can't work together. I've tried to put `karma:unit:run` to `watch` config and it works, but loads karma config on every file change. And this thing I don't like:

```
Running "karma:unit:run" (karma) task
[2014-05-25 01:40:24.466] [DEBUG] config - Loading config /Users/.../test/karma.config.js
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (0.011 secs / 0.012 secs)
```

Is there any possibility to resolve this issue or better to run those tasks separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent) to run both the watch and karma tasks:

```js
concurrent: {
  target: {
    tasks: ['karma:unit', 'watch']
  }
}
```

Then run the concurrent task from your dev task:

```js
grunt.registerTask('dev', [
  'connect',
  'jshint',
  'less:dev',
  'concurrent:target'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, these I was looking for. But need to add `logConcurrentOutput: true` for proper logging.